# About Erwin Kreyszig's definition of open sets (1.3-2)

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I was learning about basic topology in Erwin Kreyszig's *Introduction to functional analysis*.
He gives the following definition of open set:

> **1.3-2** Definition (Open set, closed set). A subset $M$ of a metric space $X$ is said to be open if it contains a ball about each of its points.

Regarding a generic *ball*: It is not clear to me if the ball should be closed ($\{x \in X \mid d(x, y) \leq \epsilon \}$ for some $y \in X$), or open ($d(x, y) < ε$), or either. The Wikipedia definition, on the other hand, uses open balls:

> A subset $U$ of a metric space $(M, d)$ is called open if, for any point $x$ in $U$, there exists a real number $\epsilon > 0$ such that any point $y \in M$ satisfying $d(x, y) < \epsilon$ belongs to $U$.

Is Kreyszig's definition not in contradiction with Wikipedia?

Comment: There is no difference. You can take open balls or closed balls in the definition.

Comment: If it contains a closed ball, then it certainly contains an open ball, and conversely.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson the converse doesn't work right?

Comment: If it contains the closed ball of radius $r$, then it contains the open ball of radius $r/2$, doesn't it?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sure, I intended your 'conversely' as: if it contains an open ball of radius $\boldsymbol{r}$ it contains the closed ball of radius $\boldsymbol{r}$ which doesn't look true to me.

Comment: You're right, erma. I suppose if it contains an open ball of radius $r$ then it contains a closed ball of radius $r/2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kreyszig's definition is in fact unusual because

1. he does not make precise what a ball about a point is,
2. he does not specify whether the ball is assumed to be open or closed.

The first item is a bit annoying. Certainly he means that a ball about a point $x_0 \in X$ is **a ball with center $x_0$**, but theoretically it could be any ball containing $x_0$. In the latter case all closed balls would be open in the sense of Kreyszig, and this would not make sense.

The standard definition (as in Wkipedia) works with open balls centered at the points $x_0 \in M$.

However, Kreyszig's definition and the standard definition are equivalent if we accept the above interpretation of a ball about a point -  both definitions  produce the same open sets.

1. Assume that for each $x_0\in M$ some open ball $B$ about $x_0$ is contained in $M$. Then $M$ trivially is open in the sense of Kreyszig.
2. Assume that for each $x_0\in M$ some ball $\mathcal B$ about $x_0$ is contained in $M$. Then also the open ball $B$ about $x_0$ with the same radius as  $\mathcal B$ is contained in $M$.

Comment: Thanks. Let's consider your case 2. If a *closed* ball $\mathcal{B}$ is contained in a *closed* subset $\mathbf{M}$ and then I consider the associated open ball $B$, wouldn't I jump to the conclusion that $M$ is open while it is not?

Comment: @erma If $M$ is closed and not open (note that subsets of $X$ may be both open and closed), then no boundary point of $M$ admits a ball (irrelevant whether open or closed) about it which is contained on $M$.

Comment: That's right, I forgot that $M$ is a subset indeed! Thanks @Paul Frost